# Why won't my 100% height div stretch to 100% of parent? Not a float

Tags: html, css, height

http://thestleonardsacademy.org/stlan/extracurricular.php

The `body` and `html` are 100%, the `#content` container is 100%, but the child `#newstiles` won't match the 100% height that I set. I can set a fixed height, which increases it beyond the auto height that it currently seems to use, but 100% does nothing.

I must be going mad, or missing something very obvious!

Comment: Because W3C this is only one right answer

Comment: tried html,body { min-height: 100%;} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
height: 100%;
```

to your #content style. You only defined max-height and min-height.

Comment: This appears to have worked. Still a little stumped, as this then means that #newstiles fills 100% of the viewport, meaning a scroll equalling header + footer.

However, your answer did solve the content issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the position to "absolute" on #newstiles. Then the height is 100%, but then you get some the ugly scrollbar as the total page height would be 100% + your header.

I suggest you remove the height and width, and replace them with position absolute, top: 120px (the size of your top navigation) and bottom: 0px.

Hope this was what you were looking for. :)

Comment: `position: absolute;` removes the element from the document flow, so it would play hell on the rest of the layout.