# my Child DIV is stretching beyond parent. No fixed / absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, height

http://thestleonardsacademy.org/stlan/extracurricular.php

The divs in question are #content and #newstiles.

#content is set is set at 100% height, as is newstiles, which is the child of content.
However, newstiles is matching the height of content, rather than filling the remaining space. Due to other divs inside #content, this means that a scroll bar is created with an additional scroll equalling the header and footer inside #content.

I'm basically wanting #content to be a minimum of 100% page height.
I then want fixed-size header and footer, and the #newstiles to fill up the remaining space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my 100% height div stretch to 100% of parent? Not a float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209460/why-wont-my-100-height-div-stretch-to-100-of-parent-not-a-float)

Comment: The issue specified was solved in the post you have linked. However, it brought this new issue, which I thought should be posted in a new question

Answer (score 1):

you have no `clear:` in your css, Try adding a `clear:both;` in your css.

Comment: I do not have any floats in my layout, so clears would surely not accomplish anything?

Comment: perhaps adding a <br> on your html

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add `clear:both` in your css add it directly in your _layout page just below your @RenderBody

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```